# HTML + AJAX: Formulário de contato

Tags: ajax

Tenho um formulário de contato ao lado de um mapa da google. Até aí blz. Mas to apanhando no AJAX pra fazer que quando alguém clique no ENVIAR apareça uma gear do font awesome e quando concluído com sucesso apareça um check do font awesome e limpe o formulário.

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Style inputs */
input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
     font-size: 0.7em;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

/* Style the container/contact section */
.container2 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 10px;
}
/* Create two columns that float next to eachother */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding: 20px;
     font-size: 0.7em !important;
     color: #000;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column, input[type=submit] {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div align="center">
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:600px"></div>
            </div>
        <div class="column" align="left">
            <form action="contato.php" method="POST" id="contactform">
                <label for="fullname">Seu nome</label>
                <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Nome" required>
                <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                <label for="assunto">Assunto</label>
                <input type="text" id="assunto" name="assunto" placeholder="Assunto" required>
                <label for="mensagem">Mensagem</label>
                <textarea id="mensagem" name="mensagem" placeholder="Escreva alguma coisa" style="height:170px"></textarea>
                <div align="right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
                </div>
                <br />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div align="center" id="resp"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const nome = $('input[name="fullname"]').val();
    const email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
    const assunto = $('input[name="assunto"]').val();
    const mensagem = $('textarea[name="mensagem"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'contato.php', // caminho para o script que vai processar os dados
        type: 'POST',
        data: {nome: nome, email: email, assunto: assunto, mensagem: mensagem},
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("input[type='submit']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
        },
        complete: function() {

        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#resp').html(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Se faltar alguma coisa eu posto!

Visualmente é assim:

[Figura 1 - Formulário pronto pra ser preenchido](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhY9d.png)

[Figura 2 - fa fa-spin fa-cog rodando enquanto é enviado para contato.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X5N6.png)

[Figura 3 - fa fa-check para quando concluir e aí voltar no estado da figura 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHher.png)

Comment: Seria nessa div `id="resp"` ou não?

Comment: Até pode ser ou qualquer outra que traga tudo do jeito que quero! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma camada *overlay* (uma div por cima do formulário com fundo semi-transparente) e coloque o ícone *gear* centralizado:

```
<div id="icone" class="w-100 h-100"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-6x icone" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

Coloque essa div após o fechamento `</form>`.

As classes nativas do Bootstrap (v4) `w-100` e `h-100` fazem com que a div ocupe 100% na largura e altura do contêiner. É preciso também que esse contêiner tenha `position: relative`, por isso adicione também essa propriedade em:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
```

Veja que coloquei um `id` na div e uma `class` no `<i>` do Fontawesome chamados `icone`, onde no CSS eu defino as suas propriedades:

```
#icone{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
   display: none;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

.icone{
   color: #1D03FF;
}
```

Em `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);` foi definido um fundo branco com metade de transparência (`.5`). A classe `.icone` define a cor do ícone. Isso você pode alterar como achar melhor.

Coloque no `beforeSend:` do Ajax:

```
$("#icone").css("display", "flex");
```

Isso irá exibir a div oculta com o ícone *gear* ao disparar o Ajax.

No callback `error:` coloque o código:

```
$("#icone").hide();
```

Isso irá ocultar a div caso haja algum erro no Ajax.

Em `success:` coloque o código abaixo para alterar o ícone em *check* e resetar o formulário:

```
$("#icone i").addClass("fa-check").removeClass("fa-cog");
$("#contactform").trigger("reset");
```

Comment: perfeito! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Disponha! Se puder marcar ✔ na resposta seria excelente. Abs!